# How to change format array in node js from 1 string become another object

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, concatenation

I have a json like this :

```js
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "ok",
    "data": [
        {
            "tenor": "23"
        },
        {
            "tenor": "17"
        },
        {
            "tenor": "37"
        },
        {
            "tenor": "27,29"
        },
        {
            "tenor": "33,35"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I want the result to be something like this:

```
{ "status": 1, "message": "ok", "data": [ { "tenor": "23" }, { "tenor": "17" }, { "tenor": "37" }, { "tenor": "27" }, { "tenor": "29" }, { "tenor": "33" }, { "tenor": "35" } ] }
```

What I have tried:

```
var arrayCoba = [];
var array1 = { "status": 1, "message": "ok", "data": [ { "tenor": "23" }, { "tenor": "17" }, { "tenor": "37" }, { "tenor": "27,29" }, { "tenor": "33,35" } ] }

for(var i = 0; i<array1.data.length; i++){
    var string = array1.data[i].tenor;
    var substring = ",";

    if(string.includes(substring) == true){
        var tenor = array.data[i].tenor;
        var tenorArr = tenor.split(',');
        var dataTenor = tenorArr.map(tenor => ({ tenor }));
        arrayCoba.push(dataTenor);
    }
 }

 var dataHasil = array1.data.concat(arrayCoba);

 return res.json({status:1,message:'ok',data:dataHasil});
```

but the result that i get is :

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "ok",
    "data": [
        {
            "tenor": "23"
        },
        {
            "tenor": "17"
        },
        {
            "tenor": "37"
        },
        {
            "tenor": "27,29"
        },
        {
            "tenor": "33,35"
        },
        [
            {
                "tenor": "27"
            },
            {
                "tenor": "29"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "tenor": "33"
            },
            {
                "tenor": "35"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

can anyone help me? Thank you ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var dataTenor = tenorArr.map(tenor => ({ tenor }));` return an array of tenor object.
`arrayCoba.push(dataTenor);` add the array in other array and is for this you get an array in array.

use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)  -> `arrayCoba.push(...dataTenor);`

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.data.length; i++) {
    var string = array1.data[i].tenor;
    var substring = ",";

    if (string.includes(substring) == true) {
        var tenor = array1.data[i].tenor;
        var tenorArr = tenor.split(',');
        var dataTenor = tenorArr.map(tenor => ({
            tenor
        }));
        arrayCoba.push(...dataTenor);
    } else {
        arrayCoba.push(array1.data[i]);
    }
}

var dataHasil = arrayCoba;
```

**UPDATE**: a another way with **map** operator.

```
var substring = ',';

var copyDataTenors = array1.data;
var arrayCoba = "".concat(copyDataTenors
    .map(obj => obj.tenor))
    .split(substring)
    .map(tenorString => ({
        'tenor': tenorString
    }))

var dataHasil = arrayCoba;
```

**UPDATE**: With **recursion** and **more generic** than previous solutions

```
const data = [{
        "tenor": "23"
    },
    {
        "tenor": "17"
    },
    {
        "tenor": "37"
    },
    {
        "tenor": "27,29"
    },
    {
        "tenor": "33,35"
    }
]

/**
 *
 * @param {*} fn function callback
 * @param {*} v string[] or string
 * @param {*} attr string
 * @param {*} substring string
 */
const processDeepObject = (fn, v, attr, substring) => {
    return typeof v === 'string' ? {
        [attr]: v
    } : v[attr] ? fn(v[attr].split(substring), attr, substring) : [];
}

/**
 * Version 1
 * @param {*} arr Array of objects
 * @param {*} attr target you want keep (for this use case tenor)
 * @param {*} substring which char to split the data (for this use case ',')
 */
const deepObjectFlatten = (arr, attr, substring) => [].concat(...arr.map((v) => processDeepObject(deepObjectFlatten, v, attr, substring)));



/**
 * Version 2 same as version 1 but compact
 * @param {*} arr Array of objects
 * @param {*} attr target you want keep (for this use case tenor)
 * @param {*} substring which char to split the data (for this use case ',')
 */
const deepObjectFlattenV2 = (arr, attr, substring) => [].concat(...arr.map((v) => {
    return typeof v === 'string' ? {
        [attr]: v
    } : v[attr] ? deepObjectFlattenV2(v[attr].split(substring), attr, substring) : [];
}));


console.log(deepObjectFlatten(data, 'tenor', ','))
console.log(deepObjectFlattenV2(data, 'tenor', ','))
/*
Output :
//v1
[ { tenor: '23' },
  { tenor: '17' },
  { tenor: '37' },
  { tenor: '27' },
  { tenor: '29' },
  { tenor: '33' },
  { tenor: '35' } ]

//v2
  [ { tenor: '23' },
  { tenor: '17' },
  { tenor: '37' },
  { tenor: '27' },
  { tenor: '29' },
  { tenor: '33' },
  { tenor: '35' } ]
 */
```

Comment: My pleasure  :) .

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below:

```
function test() {
    let obj = { "status": 1, "message": "ok", "data": [ { "tenor": "23" }, { "tenor": "17" }, { "tenor": "37" }, { "tenor": "27,29" }, { "tenor": "33,35" } ] }
    let res = [];
    obj.data
        .map(item => item.tenor.split(','))
        .forEach(tenors => {
            tenors.forEach(tenor => res.push({tenor}));
        });

    obj.data = res;
    return obj;
}
```

After invoking above method it returns:

```
{"status":1,"message":"ok","data":[{"tenor":"23"},{"tenor":"17"},{"tenor":"37"},{"tenor":"27"},{"tenor":"29"},{"tenor":"33"},{"tenor":"35"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were using the results returned by map in a wrong way,you can use spread operator as mentioned by John to fix this.

You can do something like this:

```js
var arrayCoba = [];
var array1 = { "status": 1, "message": "ok", "data": [ { "tenor": "23" }, { "tenor": "17" }, { "tenor": "37" }, { "tenor": "27,29" }, { "tenor": "33,35" } ] }

for(var i = 0; i<array1.data.length; i++){
    var string = array1.data[i].tenor;
    var substring = ",";

    if(string.includes(substring) == true){
        var tenor = array1.data[i].tenor;
        var tenorArr = tenor.split(',');
        var dataTenor = tenorArr.map(tenor => ({ "tenor" : tenor }));
        arrayCoba.push(...dataTenor);
    } else {
        arrayCoba.push({"tenor": array1.data[i].tenor})
    }

 }
 return res.json({status:1,message:'ok',data : arrayCoba});
```

**John,dacost** has used almost the same logic, didn't see it earlier, so have posted this.

Answer (score -2):

you get result from mongodb after result put into JSON.stringify function than get result like that "{"name":5,"value":6}"

Comment: can you explain this?

Comment: Can you give us an example of you purpose ?